# Is it possible to filter or segment an event on a user's eCommerce value?

Tags: google-analytics

Basically if you have an event set up, lets call it "Bought an Upsell", assume that it has all appropriate values set up, Action, category, label, value, noninteraction.  is there a way to answer the question, who triggered this event, where their check was less than $15?

Also API metrics, dimensions, filters, segments, would be highly preferred to anything in the online GUI.

TIA For any help.

Comment: More info:  ga:transactionRevenue does not work.  When dealing with events all of the ecommerce stats seem to add up to the total for all people who have ever seen that event.